# Rewriting a url to a php file while passing variable using .htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need to rewrite the following url

```
component/iproperty/?view=property&id=53
```

to go to

```
redirect.php?id=53
```

using the .htaccess file

the id=53 can be any id at all (always a number)

Answer (score 2):

In your .htaccess ...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^component/iproperty/?view=property&id=([0-9]+)?$  redirect.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This won't work, because the query string isn't tested against the regex in a `RewriteRule`

Comment: but it does work! thought to be fair, @rukmi-patel got it even better with "&id=(\d+)?$"

Comment: Hmm.. you're right. It does work! Weird, I've read a few articles on not being able to match against query strings like that and mine works too even though I match `$` before the query string. Now I'm confused haha

Comment: you definitely know more about .htaccess than i do. is there a performance improvement with your method, or is it just a different approach?

Comment: It's just different. Your's might perform slightly faster even since it only has one regex to match against instead of two, but the difference would be nanoseconds.

Comment: This doesnt work for me sorry guys. Can I use it with other rewrite rules ? I put it first in the file but nothing

Comment: maybe post your entire .htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

This wil do exactly what you asked for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=property&id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^component/iproperty/?$ /redirect.php?id=%1 [L]
```

Change `[L]` to `[R=301,L]` if you want it to redirect the user's browser.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^component/iproperty/?view=property&id=([0-9]+)?$  redirect.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^component/iproperty/?view=property&id=(\d+)?$  redirect.php?id=$1 [L]
```